# Flatten a tuple inside a list that contains other type of object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list that is like a matrioska, fortunately it does attain to a format, which is [(),int]

Example:

```
    [[('spring', 'flowers'), 1], [('spring', 'birds'), 1], [('autumn', 'leaves'), 3],[('autumn', 'mild'), 1], [('summer', 'sun'), 2]]
```

I am trying to get this:

```
    [['spring', 'flowers', 1], ['spring', 'birds', 1], ['autumn', 'leaves', 3],['autumn', 'mild', 1], ['summer', 'sun', 2]]
```

I tried to unpack the tuple, using the formula:

```
   [(a, *rest) for a, rest in list]
```

And the error is:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I also tried to separate the elements in sublists, but couldn't keep the order to bring them together again:

```
   season    = list(x[0] for x in info if isinstance(x,tuple))
   property  = list(x[1] for x in info if isinstance(x,tuple))
   times     = list(x for x in info if isinstance(x,int))
```

Comment: `[[x, y, z] for (x, y), z in info]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements are syntactically equal, then you can use.

```py
lst = [[('spring', 'flowers'), 1], [('spring', 'birds'), 1], [('autumn', 'leaves'), 3],[('autumn', 'mild'), 1], [('summer', 'sun'), 2]]

[[x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1]] for x in lst]

# [['spring', 'flowers', 1], ['spring', 'birds', 1], ['autumn', 'leaves', 3], ['autumn', 'mild', 1], ['summer', 'sun', 2]]
```